# FunctionConstructor.prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, proto

If

```js
let variable = new FunctionConstructor();
```

then `variable.__proto__` = `FunctionConstructor.prototype`. What is `variable .__ proto__` (the object from which `variable` is inherited) is clear, but what is equal to the `prototype` property of a constructor function is not.

1. "What semantic meaning (preferably related to real world objects) does `FunctionConstructor.prototype` have?"
2. If `let variable = new FunctionConstructor ();`, then, on the one hand, `variable` inherits from `FunctionConstructor` (since it was created using the operator `new FunctionConstructor ();`), and on the other hand, `variable .__ proto __ = FunctionConstructor.prototype` (again because it was created with the `new` operator), i.e. `variable` prototypically inherits from `FunctionConstructor.prototype`. What is the difference between prototypal inheritance and normal inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

> What semantic meaning [...] does `FunctionConstructor.prototype` have?

It is an object that was created at the time that `FunctionConstructor` was defined. So whenever a function is defined, it immediately gets an object property (`prototype`). Some exceptions exist where functions cannot be used as constructors (e.g. arrow functions, members of a `class` definition, ...).

This object can be given members like any other object. In old style code you'll often see `FunctionConstructor.prototype.myMethod = ....`. In modern versions you'll see the `class` syntax, which results in similar initialisation of that `prototype` object.

This object will serve as a prototype whenever the constructor is invoked with `new`. When such invocation takes place, even before any statement of that function is executed, a new object is created that will be `this` during the function's execution and will be returned by `new`. That `this` object will have its `__proto__` property set to that prototype object, establishing the prototype chain. So this is the moment that the prototype starts to play its role.

> If `let variable = new FunctionConstructor ();`, then, on the one hand, variable inherits from `FunctionConstructor` (since it was created using the operator `new FunctionConstructor ();`),

No, this is not true. The `variable` will not inherit anything from `FunctionConstructor`. `FunctionConstructor` is an object (a function object) with its own prototype (which is not its `prototype` property, but its `__proto__` property), and that chain has nothing to do with `variable` at all.

It helps to visualise these two independent prototype chains. See [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/5459839), where I elaborated on this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880438/5459839).

> ...and on the other hand, `variable.__ proto __ = FunctionConstructor.prototype` (again because it was created with the `new` operator), i.e. `variable` prototypically inherits from `FunctionConstructor.prototype`.

This is true.

> What is the difference between prototypal inheritance and normal inheritance?

There are many differences. Here are a few:

Classical inheritance relies on classes, which provide the template for instances. Classes define a hierarchy, but instances cannot inherit from each other. Prototypal inheritance relies on constructors and their `prototype` property. Prototypes are just objects, and can be modified, classes not.

Read more:

- [Understanding the difference between classical and prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568733/5459839),
- [Benefits of prototypal inheritance over classical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16872315/5459839)
- [Prototype based vs. class based inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816075/5459839)
- [Classical inheritance vs prototypal inheritance in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640910/5459839)